# streamer not recording audio

Tags: audio, video, recording

I am trying to record a video from my webcam with streamer, this is my command:

```
streamer -t 1:0:0 -c /dev/video0 -f rgb24 -r 5  -o   outfile.avi
```

Unfortunately this is not recording any audio, which is the correct set of options then?